# How to set style of element loaded into <object> as data

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I've recently inherited some code that I need to maintain, part of which is a web-app meant to be used on iPad.

Unfortunately, the recent iOS 8 update broke a part of said web-app.

In one section, the web-app contained an iframe which loaded in a list of items. This iframe used to scroll with only one finger when run as a web-app, but now only scrolls with two fingers. *** The one finger vs. two finger scrolling of iframe content in iOS web-apps is a whole other can of worms, and NOT what I'm looking for help with though *** - I need help with implementing my solution.

If I place the content in a div I can get it to scroll as I want, however, I then also have to use an object to load in the content (coming from a separate page) - this is where my jQuery problem arises.

When an item is selected from the loaded list it is highlighted - once the user is finished and his/her selections are submitted the "highlighted" items are then "deselected" using jQuery to remove the "highlighted" style.

This worked fine with the iframe, but I can't manage to change the styling of the items now that they are contained within a div and object.

Here are some code snippets to illustrate what's going on:

ORIGINAL (works correctly with iframe)

```
<iframe id="myiframe" src="item_list.html"></iframe>

<script>
    function deselect()
    {
        var itemcount = $('#ItemCount').val();

        for (var i = 0; i < itemcount; i++) {
            // item ids are named a1, a2, a3, etc.
            $("#myiframe").contents().find("#a" + i).css("font-size", "26px");
            $("#myiframe").contents().find("#a" + i).css("font-weight", "normal");
            $("#myiframe").contents().find("#a" + i).css("color", "#3A3B3B");
        }
    }
</script>
```

MY ATTEMPT (not working)

```
<div id="myiframe">
    <object id="myloader" type="text/html" data="item_list.html" ></object>
</div>

<script>
    function deselect()
    {
        var itemcount = $('#ItemCount').val();

        for (var i = 0; i < itemcount; i++) {
            // item ids are named a1, a2, a3, etc.

            //doesn't work - I think contents() is specifically for iframes?
            $("#myiframe, #myloader").contents().find("#a" + i).css("font-size", "26px");

            // none of these work
            var path = "#myiframe, #myloader, #a" + i ;
            var path = "#myiframe, #a" + i ;
            var path = "#myloader, #a" + i ;
            var path = "#a" + i ;

            $(path).css("font-size", "26px");

            // none of these work
            var path = "#myiframe, #myloader" ;
            var path = "#myiframe" ;
            var path = "#myloader" ;

            $(path).find("#a" + i).css("font-size", "26px");

            // someone suggested using data() but it didn't work for me
            // either AND I don't think that that's how it's used anyhow

        }
    }
</script>
```

Admittedly, I'm not really a jQuery guy, but this seems like it should be fairly easy...

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though I think it's better to use ajax to load the content into a div (and a single DOM), I found a way to access the document within the `<object>` element.

`$("#a0", $("#myloader")[0].contentDocument)` will select the `a0` element in the document held within the `object` data.

The second parameter to the jquery selection is the context in which to search, `$("#myloader)[0]` returns the [HTMLObjectElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLObjectElement) (and is equivalent to `document.getElementById('myloader')`, and `contentDocument` returns the HTML document retrieved via `data` attribute.

```
function deselect()
{
    var itemcount = $('#ItemCount').val();

    for (var i = 0; i < itemcount; i++) {
        // item ids are named a1, a2, a3, etc.

        //searches the content document within the object tag
        $("#a"+i, $("#myloader")[0].contentDocument).css("font-size", "26px");

        // I still think you should use .addClass() and .removeClass() 
        // (or data attributes if you want to be super fancy),
        // changing the styles with CSS,
        // rather than manipulate the styles directly in javascript.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Joe - that worked for me! I accepted this answer because it answered my question specifically, but I do agree with your suggestion to load the content in differently. As I mentioned though, I inherited this code, and I'm not all that experienced with jQuery. There seem to be a lot of things I would have done differently in this app, but I'm hesitant to tweak it any more than absolutely necessary. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason for using an `<object>` element? Jquery has a method `.load()` which will request and insert the returned data/html into an element. http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
<div id="myiframe">
  <div id="myloader"></div>
</div>
```

Then you would load the data:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
   $(function() {
     $('#myloader').load("item_list.html", function() {
        //at this point, the elements are in the document:
        $('#a0').css("font-size", "26px");
        //...
     });
   });

   function deselect() {
     var itemcount = $('#ItemCount').val();
     for (var i = 0; i < itemcount; i++) {
       $('#a'+i).css("font-size", "26px");
       //etc.
     }
   }
</script>
```

I would add that instead of manually editing the css in javascript, you use jquery to `.addClass()`, `removeClass()`, or `.toggleClass()` css classes which contain the styling you are looking for.